# Caching problem when replacing image on first load

Tags: jquery

I am having a caching problem in that when the page first loads the images are not displayed on first load when clearing the cache. I am working with an external media company that provide the images. I have wrote the below code inside a callback function to replace the source of the image once loaded.

Am I doing this correct?

```
$('img').each(function(){

    var img = $(this);

    // AJAX HEAD request to check the larger image file has loaded 
    var img_src_large = img.attr("src").replace("/viewfinder.jpg", "_SMALL.jpg");

    $.ajax({
        url: img_src_large,
        type:'HEAD',
        error:
            function(){
                img.fadeIn("fast");
            },
        success:
            function(){
                img.attr("src",img_src_large).fadeIn("fast");
            }
    });

});
```

Comment: I came across this blog post although I was not able to get it to work. http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1007-jQuery-Attr-Function-Doesn-t-Work-With-IMAGE-complete.htm#comments_16704

Comment: I just did a double take here, you're trying to trick the browser into caching it by having read the image via an ajax request?

Comment: Using AJAX was just an example that I tried to get it to work. All I am trying to do is change the source of the images with the replace(). This works fine if the image is in the browser cache although not on first load

Comment: Can anybody help with this? I need to fix this problem in my script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by force-triggering the "load" event on images that are already loaded due to caching. You can replace the fadeIn part by the logic you want.

```
$('img').hide().one("load",function(){
    $(this).fadeIn(500);
}).each(function(){
    if(this.complete) $(this).trigger("load");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with the img load, maybe this will help somebody in the same situation.

```
// Wrap Thumb Views
$('#rfxViews img').each(function(){

    var img = $(this); // cache selected to variable

    // Replace the small swatch images
    var img_src_large = img.attr("src").replace("/viewfinder.jpg", "_SMALL.jpg");

    // Set empty source until image has loaded below
    img.attr("src","");

    img.attr('src', img_src_large).hide().load(function(){
       $(this).show()
    })

});
```